# Artifactory Derby DB Migration to Oracle

Tags: oracle, migration, artifactory, derby

We are currently running Artifactory with the built-in Derby DB, and wanting to migrate to Oracle.  So we follow the steps in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Database to migrate data.  In data export, I selected "Exclude Content".

We configured Artifactory with LDAP and after migration, the LDAP configs are all in place and login is working fine with LDAP.  Everything seems OK but when I check the Permission and Groups, none got migrated over to Oracle.  Am I missing something here?  Do I need to recreate the Permissions and Groups?  My understanding and assumption are that, everything will be migrated over.

Comment: Did you perform a System level export/import (as opposed to just repositories)? which version of Artifactory are you running?

Comment: System level.  Version 6.7.3

Comment: This should not happen, system export include groups and permissions. Can you please open a Jira ticket with all the details at https://www.jfrog.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa ?